# get client and peer use name in an ongoing voice call in webrtc coturn?

Tags: webrtc, coturn

I am using **CO-TURN** as my **VoIP** platform.
What I am looking for is that how can I get information about which users are in an ongoing voice call?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you are creating sessions on turn server. You can check it from WebUi.
But your application server should manage all this not turn server as this is not role of turn server.